# Variable remains null after I use setter in JavaFx

Tags: java, variables, javafx

I am trying to make a banking system in Java using JavaFX. What I want to do is to set the text of a label to the String value of a variable when switching scene. I have a set method in the second scene's controller but the variables remains null and i don't know why.

Here is the first scene's controller. The variable ACCOUNT_NUMBER is ok, i do not have any problem. Also I want to point out that validate(conn , ACCOUNT_NUMBER, PIN) is for the database's function and is working.

```
public class LogInController extends SQLConnection{

    @FXML
    private TextField accountNumberTextField;

    @FXML
    private TextField pinTextField;

    Scene scene;
    Stage stage;

    public void logIn(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {

        final String ACCOUNT_NUMBER = accountNumberTextField.getText();
        final int PIN = Integer.parseInt(pinTextField.getText());

        if(accountNumberTextField.getText().isEmpty() || pinTextField.getText().isEmpty()){
            Dialog<String> dialog = new Dialog<>();
            dialog.setTitle("You need to complete all the fields");
            dialog.setContentText("You need to write your account number and pin.");
            ButtonType type = new ButtonType("Ok");
            dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(type);
            dialog.show();
        }

        if(!validate(conn, ACCOUNT_NUMBER, PIN)){

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("dashboard.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            DashboardController dashboardController = loader.getController();
            dashboardController.setNUMBER_ACCOUNT(ACCOUNT_NUMBER);

            stage = (Stage)((Node)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        }

    }
}
```

```
public class DashboardController implements Initializable {

   @FXML
   private Label numberAccountLabel;

   String NUMBER_ACCOUNT;

   // Here is where I have the problem. the variable NUMBER_ACCOUNT remains null. I know that the     variable should have not been written like this.

    public void setNUMBER_ACCOUNT(String numberAccount){
        NUMBER_ACCOUNT = numberAccount;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

    numberAccountLabel.setText(NUMBER_ACCOUNT);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `initialize()` method is called during the execution of `FXMLLoader.load()`, which is before you call `setNumberAccount(...)` (aside: please use proper naming conventions when you post code publicly). So `NUMBER_ACCOUNT` (same comment) is still null in `initialize()`.

Comment: @James_D thank you for your comment! It really helped me, I did not know what you just told me! :D